# Site keeps loading scrolled down instead of at the top of the page like it should

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, loading

Check out this link: http://www.ffwdcam.com/beta/

For some reason when I load it the page always loads scrolled down to the "see it in action" section! I have no idea why this is happening! Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The page scrolls to an external iframe:

```
<div class="video-block">
    <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5BqZnU2U   <!-- etc -->
```

The code in this iframe grabs focus by setting `tabindex="1"` on the player.
Possibly it also sets the player to focus `.focus()`.

Assuming the code on google doc's is out of your control, you might want to try to scroll *your* `top` window back up after the iframe is loaded.

[articulate](http://www.articulate.com/support/storyline/iframe-content-automatically-grabs-focus-in-web-browser) mentions two other solutions (to the same problem) by the way:

- Place the iFrame at the top of the web page
- Use a different web browser